# Как убрать rel canonical в drupal 6?

Tags: drupal

Как убрать `rel canonical` в `drupal 6`?

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://test.ru/test/test/" /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В шаблоне удали. Если не можешь сам, то кинь исходники шаблона.